# Separate "voltage dividers" for multiple AC sources

Tags: ac, audio, mixer

Say we have two AC sources in a circuit. Is it possible to create separately control the output coming from each source using voltage dividers? (No op-amps)

E.g. So that you have $$V_{out}=aV_1+bV_2$$

The image shows something I threw together while thinking about this, whichh might illustrate what I'm aiming for, though this setup won't do what I want to do.

[image]

The purpose of this is I want to mix the outputs of two guitar pickups using two different potentiometers.

Comment: You would never use circa 500 ohm pots directly on a guitar pup.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably noticed, turning one potentiometer of your illustration to zero will short the output to ground and you will have silence.
A common solution is to wire the pots backwards so that turning to zero shorts out the pick-up up and leaves the potentiometer resistance in series with the output. This works because the pickup has a high output impedance.

[image]

*Figure 1. Standard two-pickup wiring. Note that the switch is usually a 1-both-2 type rather than centre-off as shown in the diagram. Tone controls can be omitted if not required. Image source: [Harmony](http://harmony.demont.net/documents/schematics/standard_2pickups.php).*

The top portion of each pot forms a simple resistive mixer and the one with the lower value resistance will contribute more to the output.

Comment: So in this schema, do the volume knobs act as mixer sliders? Also, would this work with single coils?

Comment: A mixer slider is electrically identical to a rotary pot. In one the resistance trick is linear and in the other it's most of a circle. If you have a single coil it would be the same as switching the coil selector to that pickup only, wouldn't it?